# Georgian in sharelatex

Tags: unicode, sharelatex

I need to create a book for a friend of mine and I thought that Latex would best fit for this job. Plus this will be a very good opportunity to learn this powerful tool.

The problem is that the book is written in Georgians and I don't know the way to support them. I have created a small sample with a Georgian poem but after compilation its not showing the letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Poem}    
\date{February 2014}    
\begin{document}

\maketitle

ვახტანგ მეფე  ტახტზე  იჯდა,
რომ  დაიპყრეს  ოსმალთ  ქართლი.
წელში  გაწყდა  გლეხ-კაცობა,
დაუწესეს  დიდი  ხარკი.


\end{document}
```

Can you provide me with some resources to start writing in Georgian?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you can post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried so far and then people will be able to better help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you compile this with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, provided the TeX distribution is sufficiently up-to-date:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont={*},
  BoldFont={*-Bold},
  ItalicFont={*-Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic},
]{DejaVuSerif}

\title{Poem}
\author{Somebody}
\date{February 2014}    
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{verse}
ვახტანგ მეფე  ტახტზე  იჯდა,\\
რომ  დაიპყრეს  ოსმალთ  ქართლი.\\
წელში  გაწყდა  გლეხ-კაცობა,\\
დაუწესეს  დიდი  ხარკი.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

The `\setmainfont` declaration can be simpler if DejaVu Serif is installed as a system font, and it can become

```
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
```

[image]

I'm not sure if ShareLaTeX uses a TeX distribution that has the required features. You might try also `FreeSerif` instead of `DejaVu`

```
\setmainfont[
  Extension=.otf, % <--- note .otf
  UprightFont={*},
  BoldFont={*Bold},
  ItalicFont={*Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={*BoldItalic},
]{FreeSerif}
```

[image]